# Copy files from authenticated windows server to Unix server

Tags: windows, unix, pentaho

I have a set of zip files that need to be copied from an authenticated windows server to a unix server which is authenticated too.

I have tried using Pentaho but have not found any success. Is there any other alternative way with which this copy can be done like using scripts or any such method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried Pentaho kettles a File Transfer Step like 'SSH2 Put' to do file uploading and then use kitchen.bat to automate the job in Windows Task Scheduler? what are the issues you encountered with pentaho?

Comment: Hi, Yes I used the step but am not able to connect to the server through the step. I get an authentication failed error when I select the remote file path.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server supports ssh..

[Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) comes with a utility called pscp which works the same as scp.

To copy a file you would typically do this:

```
pscp myfile.zip me@myserver:/my_directory/.
```

There is also [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) if you want something more GUI.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am actually looking for something that does not involve anything manual. There are thousands of such files which we need to copy on a daily basis so anything like a script that automatically executes the copy would be helpful. The file size is pretty large which makes manual copy using winscp difficult.

Comment: What scripting language do you want to use?

Comment: Unix would be useful.

Comment: Unix is an operating system.

Comment: Lol my bad. Some script that could run well on Unix. Shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Use scp command. For more detail visit http://www.garron.me/en/linux/scp-linux-mac-command-windows-copy-files-over-ssh.html